# Relocating panels gets mixed up WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application using C# and WinForms. I have three panels. Two of them are fairly large and are currently positioned side by side. I am trying to implement a feature for users who have smaller screens or wish to have the form as a smaller size. I am relocating the right panel underneath the middle one and re-centering them in the form. 
The issue that I have though is when the user scrolls down and re-sizes the form again the two middle panels (the big ones) move lower in the form leaving a chunk of blank space at the top.

My code is fairly simple

```
namespace ResizeCheck
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point originalLeft, originalRight;
        bool flag = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            originalLeft = leftInnerPanel.Location;
            originalRight = rightInnerPanel.Location;
        }
        private void vertical()//move the right panel under the left one
        {
            leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - leftInnerPanel.Width / 2, 5);
            if (leftInnerPanel.Location.X <= buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width)
            {
                leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width, leftInnerPanel.Location.Y);
            }
            rightInnerPanel.Location = new Point(leftInnerPanel.Location.X, leftInnerPanel.Height + 10);
            MessageBox.Show("inside vertical " + leftInnerPanel.Location.Y);
        }

        private void horizontal()//relocate to their original horizontal position
        {
            leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width + 10, 5);
            if (leftInnerPanel.Location.X <= buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width)
            {
                leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width, leftInnerPanel.Location.Y);
            }
            rightInnerPanel.Location = new Point(leftInnerPanel.Location.X + leftInnerPanel.Width + 20, 5);
            MessageBox.Show("inside horizontal " + leftInnerPanel.Location.Y);
        }

        private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//handler for when the form is resized by the user
        {
            if ((leftInnerPanel.Width + rightInnerPanel.Width + buttonPanel.Width) >= this.Width)
            {
                vertical();
                //flag = true;
            }
            else if ((leftInnerPanel.Width + rightInnerPanel.Width + buttonPanel.Width) + 50 < this.Width)
            {
                horizontal();
                //flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My designer code is also fairly simple.

```
namespace ResizeCheck
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.rightInnerPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.leftInnerPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.buttonPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // rightInnerPanel
            // 
            this.rightInnerPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            this.rightInnerPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.rightInnerPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(887, 13);
            this.rightInnerPanel.Name = "rightInnerPanel";
            this.rightInnerPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(662, 936);
            this.rightInnerPanel.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // leftInnerPanel
            // 
            this.leftInnerPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            this.leftInnerPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.leftInnerPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, 13);
            this.leftInnerPanel.Name = "leftInnerPanel";
            this.leftInnerPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(662, 936);
            this.leftInnerPanel.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // buttonPanel
            // 
            this.buttonPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.buttonPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.buttonPanel.Name = "buttonPanel";
            this.buttonPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 258);
            this.buttonPanel.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 601);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rightInnerPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.buttonPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.leftInnerPanel);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.SizeChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_SizeChanged);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel rightInnerPanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel leftInnerPanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel buttonPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't easier to use a SplitContainer adjusting its orientation?

Comment: I am not familiar with SplitContainers. I tried using a Container Panel that would help with positioning the inner panels (the two big ones) but still messes things up

Comment: SplitContainer will resize (unless it's fixed) and changing its orientation from vertical to horizontal you'll change 2nd panel position (right side or bottom).

Comment: Also you can use `table layout panel` and set width and height of panels by percent, since you can add only one control in each cell, do not forget to put a panel in each cell first then add controls on that panels

Comment: Any actual solutions to my problem? I mean lately this place is becoming very weird. A few weeks ago I asked a question about frames and the only answers were "Don't use frames and here's why". Now I am asking a question with panels with specific sizes that I wish to move one form size changes and the answers are do not use panels, use something else.....

Comment: The issue could be your calculation of the `leftInnerPanel.Location` in `vertical()`/`horizontal()` funcs, in combination with scroll bars ON. Check the logic - it can be done.

Comment: @elimad  Well the only issue is with vertical, horizontal works perfectly. Now what I am using is simply calculating the location based on the Form size. If you read my code again you will notice the the `Location.Y` property of `leftInnerPanel` is not really changed in code. I am simply copying it again and again whenever it is moved. The only thing that changes is `leftInnerPanel.Location.X`, `rightInnerPanel.Location.X` and `rightInnerPanel.Location.Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for how much the form has scrolled, you are simply plopping the panel at the top of the visible client area.

Change your `Vertical()` method thusly:

```
    private void vertical()
    {
        leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - leftInnerPanel.Width / 2, 5 - VerticalScroll.Value);
        if (leftInnerPanel.Location.X <= buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width)
            leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(buttonPanel.Location.X + buttonPanel.Width, leftInnerPanel.Location.Y);
        rightInnerPanel.Location = new Point(leftInnerPanel.Location.X, leftInnerPanel.Bottom + 10);
    }
```

Two points to note:

1) use of the `VerticalScroll` member.

2) use of `Bottom` instead of `Height` (and `Right` instead of `Width` in the `Horizontal()` method).

Comment: Thank you sir for giving me an actual answer instead of suggesting I use other methods

Answer (score 1):

In `vertical()`
since you are not adjusting the `Y` of `leftInnerPanel`, we can straightaway use the `buttonPanel.Top`

```
leftInnerPanel.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - leftInnerPanel.Width / 2, buttonPanel.Top);
```

Secondly,

```
//rightInnerPanel.Location = new Point(leftInnerPanel.Location.X, leftInnerPanel.Height + 10);
rightInnerPanel.Location = new Point(leftInnerPanel.Location.X, leftInnerPanel.Bottom + 10);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for giving me an actual answer instead of suggesting I use other methods. Although your method did not seem to work as much as the other answer I still give you an upvote because most of the time at this website the answers are telling me use another method, I don't like the method you are using

Comment: thanks and I agree @DonBoitnott's should be a better answer, though i didn't try it. About suggestions to use other methods: sometimes we get totally different directions and that is what forums are for ;) - take it cool. cheers

Comment: I don't mind suggestions, what I mind is only getting suggestions and never an actual solution.:P anw